# Android web browser without closed source components

Tags: android, open-source, web-browser

I'm looking for an Android web browser, that:

- Is free, gratis and open source (and doesn't include closed source components like Google Play Services)
- Uses an embedded Chromium runtime (and not a system webview)
- Has an built-in adblocker (which should use at least EasyList and EasyPrivacy by default, where it should be possible to add lists and with support for element-hiding rules)
- Blocks third-party cookies
- Supports SOCKS proxies
- Has chronological history (which should be automatically cleared on exit)
- Has an unlimited amount of tabs
- Has bookmarks (with folders and a daily backup to a secured WebDAV share or Git server)
- Has a scroll indicator
- Has advanced DuckDuckGo search (like in the desktop browser [Min](https://github.com/minbrowser/min))
- Has ARM64 builds available
- Is still maintained

Comment: Many wishes at once :) I'm not acutely aware of any browser meeting them all, but be welcome to see my [Web Browser](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser) app list. Concentrate on those apps having an F-Droid (or IzzyOnDroid) icon along as an indicator for being open-source, and check their descriptions (e.g. Github-links) for your requirements – while waiting for a real answer to pop up. Fingers crossed!